# Modify default wordpress category widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the default Wordpress category widget to add a font awesome icon before the category text.

I've found the php class that generates the widget, but can't work out where - or if it's even possible to include an icon.

This is what is output by the widget currently:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
        <a href="http://site.co.uk/?cat=1" title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized">
            Uncategorized
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
        <a href="http://site.co.uk/?cat=1" title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized">
            <i class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></i>
            Uncategorized
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The class you are referring to is defined in your stylesheet. Classes are defined in stylesheets with a "." at the beginning. Thus, if you were to search through your theme's stylesheet.css file or style.css file you should see the following entries:

```
.cat-item {
 //some characteristics defined in here
 }

.cat-item-1 {
 //some characteristics defined in here
 }
```

You can edit one or both of these and include the following inside the braces: `list-style-image: url('location-of-your-awesome-icon.gif')`

Alternately, if you don't know what kinds of things these classes have been added to (if they're applied to stuff that's not lists, for instance), you might consider adding a new class in your stylesheet and then just including it everywhere you want it to appear, like so:

```
.awesome-icon {
    list-style-image: url('location-of-your-awesome-icon.gif');
}
```

And then edit the code you linked above to include your new css class:

```
  `<li class="cat-item cat-item-1 awesome-icon">`
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add a filter function to functions.php of your theme;
for instance:

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'add_span_cat_count');
function add_span_cat_count($links) {
$links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span>(', $links);
$links = str_replace(')', ')</span>', $links);
return $links;
}
```

if you need a css class on the span, add it here in the above:

for instance:

```
<span class="cat-count">
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same thing. Currently, I'm thinking of a custom widget. The category widget should be in wp-includes/default_widgets.php so you may be able to use that code to base the custom widget on.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
ul li.cat-item a:before{
  #your icon css
}
```